# problem with choosing data type for large file

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle9i

I create a program to insert Large file into database (around 10M). I choosed BLOB type for objects column in my table.

Now I read BLOB just support binary object with maximoum lengh of 4M.

would you advice me what can I do in this case for upload those object more than 4M?

I am useing Oracle 9i or 10g.

Comment: Why exactly do you need to store these files in a database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You read something that appears to be incorrect.

Per the [Oracle 10g Release 2 documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#sthref168):

```
 The BLOB datatype stores unstructured binary large objects. BLOB objects 
 can be thought of as bitstreams with no character set semantics. BLOB 
 objects can store binary data up to (4 gigabytes -1) * (the value of the 
 CHUNK parameter of LOB storage).  

 If the tablespaces in your database are of standard block size, and if you 
 have used the default value of the CHUNK parameter of LOB storage when 
 creating a LOB column, then this is equivalent to (4 gigabytes - 1) *
 (database block size).
```

Comment: Oh thanks so I think this book that I read made mistake they write blob just can support 4Megabyte!Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> The maximum size of a LOB supported by
>   the database is equal to the value of
>   the db_block_size initialization
>   parameter times the value 4294967295.
>   This allows for a maximum LOB size
>   ranging from 8 terabytes to 128
>   terabytes.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i1016062

Comment: Oh thanks so I think this book that I read made mistake they write blob just can support 4Megabyte!Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to this site,

```
http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-datatypes.html
```

BLOB has a max size of 4GB since Oracle 8, so 10MB should be no problem.

Comment: Oh thanks so I think this book that I read made mistake they write blob just can support 4Megabyte!Thanks